# Average Queueing Delay/End-to-End Delay

Tags: delay, end-to-end, packet-loss

I am trying to figure out a problem where I calculate the average queueing delay where N packets are being sent of length L bits from Host A to Host B. There are two links between A and B (there is one router between A and B). The link connected to A has a transmission rate of `R1` bps and the link connected to B has a transmission rate of `R2` bps. I am disregarding propagation delay.

1.) What is the average queueing delay of the packets at the router if `R1` > `R2`?

2.) What is the average end to end delay of the packets if `R1` > `R2`?

What I know is that to figure out queueing delay it is packet length (L) over link bandwidth (R) and I have N packets.

```
L/R = queueing delay
```

I am not sure how to answer these questions with the information provided. This is the first time I have dealt with these type of questions. I find them interesting I would just really like some help in how to solve them or if someone has a solution with some explanation I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!